# If I update ResultSet and then I do a get on the same ResultSet, I still receive the "old" db version tuple

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, resultset

```
myresultset.updateInt("qty",newqty);
myresultset.getInt("qty");    // I still receive the value before the updateInt
```

How to do update my ResultSet locally and get the local updated value?

Comment: Which database system and JDBC driver are you using? What does `DatabaseMetaData.ownUpdatesAreVisible(..)` return for the result-set type of your result set? (if it returns false, then your driver doesn't support this intentionally)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel

`mariadb`, `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

where should I put `DatabaseMetaData.ownUpdatesAreVisible(..)` ?

Comment: You can retrieve the database metadata object using `DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData()`, and then inspect its value using `System.out.println(dbmd.ownUpdatesAreVisible(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY))` (or whatever result set type you're using). As an aside, for MariaDB, you should use MariaDB Connector/J, not MySQL Connector/J.